# Rep from Area 51 doesn't show up in notification bar

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, notification-bar

Currently, new rep gained from posting on-topic suggestion-questions on Area 51 does **not** show up in the notification bar on top, like it would for any other site (including Meta).

Is this a bug? .....I would certainly like to be notified if people are up/downvoting my questions on Area 51.

Comment: This is a limitation of the Area51 stack.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I figured that one out.....what do you mean? [are you suggesting that this should be tagged [tag:feature-request]?]

Comment: It's a duplicate, trying to find a canonical. The devs have stated that Area51 will not be updated to add the functionality.

Comment: Hm....checked possible duplicates (under title of new question), didn't find any that had what I was looking for.....

Comment: @MartijnPieters You got it; thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm thinking of [leaving it here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) rather than deleting it...have voted to close.

Comment: That's fine, yes.